# Install list of charts in parallel with ok status

Tags: go, kubernetes, concurrency, parallel-processing, kubernetes-helm

I use the following code which works and installs helm charts.
I got a list of charts and it installs each chart (via loop) and wait (`upgradeAction.Wait = true`, see below ) that the chart is up and running (using the `wait=true` flag of the helm) and then install the next one, the problem is that it takes a **lot of time** to wait that each chart is up-and-running **and just then proceed to the next one**, Is there a way to install **all in parallel** and just verify at the end (of all the charts installations)  that it works (like how the wait works but for list of charts).

Here is the code:

```
mpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile(kp, kcp)
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err, "error")
}

defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name()) 

if _, err := tmpfile.Write(cfg); err != nil {
    return err
}
if err := tmpfile.Close(); err != nil {
    return err
}

kcfgFilePath := tmpfile.Name()
settings := cli.New()
ac := new(action.Configuration)
clientGetter := genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false)
clientGetter.KubeConfig = &kcfgFilePath

for _, chartInstallation := range charts {
    chart, err := loader.Load(chartInstallation.Path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    releaseName := releaseName + "-" + chartInstallation.Name
    if err := ac.Init(clientGetter, settings.Namespace(), os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), func(format string, v ...interface{}) {
        
    }); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    releasePresent := true
    statusAction := action.NewStatus(ac)
    status, err := statusAction.Run(releaseName)
    if err != nil {
        if strings.Contains(err.Error(), driver.ErrReleaseNotFound.Error()) {
            releasePresent = false
        } else {
            return err
        }
    }

    if !releasePresent {
        // install chart
        installAction := action.NewInstall(ac)
        installAction.CreateNamespace = true
        installAction.Namespace = chartInstallation.Namespace
        installAction.ReleaseName = releaseName

        _, err := installAction.Run(chart, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        log.Info("chart installed: ", "releaseName", releaseName)
    }

    if status != nil {
        if releasePresent && status.Info.Status.String() == release.StatusFailed.String() { 
            upgradeAction := action.NewUpgrade(ac)
            // HERE IT WAIT FOR THE CHART TO VERIFY THAT EVERYTHING IS UP
            upgradeAction.Wait = true
            upgradeAction.ReuseValues = false
            upgradeAction.Recreate = false
            _, err := upgradeAction.Run(releaseName, chart, nil)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change it to  `upgradeAction.Wait = false` , It starts to install all the charts without waiting to each one health checks, however not sure how can I verify it at the end of all the charts installations

Comment: use [goroutines](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#goroutines)

Comment: @Matt - thanks, well I know about goroutines, however not sure how to get the "feedbacks" from all chart installation at the end. it will be great if you can provide an example in this contexts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start goroutines for each chart you're installing (wrapping chart install code inside go routines) and then use `sync.WaitGroup` to wait all goroutines to finish. Something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    kcfgFilePath := tmpfile.Name()
    settings := cli.New()
    ac := new(action.Configuration)
    clientGetter := genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false)
    clientGetter.KubeConfig = &kcfgFilePath
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, chartInstallation := range charts {
        wg.Add(1)
        go installChart(&wg, chartInstallation.Path)
    }

    fmt.Println("Installing...")
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Installed!")
}

func installChart(wg *sync.WaitGroup, chartInstallationPath string) error {
    defer wg.Done()

    chart, err := loader.Load(chartInstallationPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    releaseName := releaseName + "-" + chartInstallation.Name
    if err := ac.Init(clientGetter, settings.Namespace(), os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), func(format string, v ...interface{}) {

    }); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    releasePresent := true
    statusAction := action.NewStatus(ac)
    status, err := statusAction.Run(releaseName)
    if err != nil {
        if strings.Contains(err.Error(), driver.ErrReleaseNotFound.Error()) {
            releasePresent = false
        } else {
            return err
        }
    }

    if !releasePresent {
        // install chart
        installAction := action.NewInstall(ac)
        installAction.CreateNamespace = true
        installAction.Namespace = chartInstallation.Namespace
        installAction.ReleaseName = releaseName

        _, err := installAction.Run(chart, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        log.Info("chart installed: ", "releaseName", releaseName)
    }

    if status != nil {
        if releasePresent && status.Info.Status.String() == release.StatusFailed.String() {
            upgradeAction := action.NewUpgrade(ac)
            // HERE IT WAIT FOR THE CHART TO VERIFY THAT EVERYTHING IS UP
            upgradeAction.Wait = true
            upgradeAction.ReuseValues = false
            upgradeAction.Recreate = false
            _, err := upgradeAction.Run(releaseName, chart, nil)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a good resource for that: https://goinbigdata.com/golang-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish/

Comment: Thanks a lot,ill try it out, btw,did you miss the `add(1)`?

Comment: @bredstraruts Indeed, I didn't have the time to test it locally. I'll update the answer.